# Is there a way to clear the chatbox in lync (skype for business)?

Tags: chat, lync, skype-for-business

Is there a way to clear the chatbox in lync (skype for business)? So that messages cannot be seen anymore?

Comment: If you are an Administrator on the domain you have the permissions to disable chat history.

Comment: I was more looking for a keyboard shortcut that is available for presenters inside lync, that clears the visible chat for all attendees (and presenters). It does not necessarily need to erase the chat history/cache files, just wiping the display, as if you left the session and came back in. But I guess this is not an implemented function yet?

Comment: Its a group policy control feature.  By default the conversation history isn't save which means, closing the window, means the conversation history isn't kept.

Comment: @Ramhound yes thats the case in our setup. But the chat is then only cleared for the user that left and reentered, but not for all. which is a feature we'r looking for.

Comment: There is no command to clear the message for all participates, the cache is local on each machine, so as an end user you can't clear the message on the other end of the conversion only on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Article how to do that.
https://kb.intermedia.net/article/3238

If you just want show or hide the instant message area you can press

> Ctrl+W

Comment: You should quote the relevant information.